# How to horizontally stack a csr matrix and a numpy.ndarry?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, concatenation

I have a problem in which I have to stack a **numpy.ndarray (which has string values in it)** and a **csr matrix (which has floating point values)**

I tried doing the following

1)

```
from scipy.sparse import hstack
from scipy import sparse
temp = hstack((image_features,sparse.csr_matrix(feature_names)))
print(temp.shape)
print(type(temp))
```

This gave me the following error

```
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)
```

2)

```
from scipy.sparse import hstack
from scipy import sparse
temp = hstack((image_features.astype(object),feature_names))
print(temp.shape)
print(type(temp))
```

This gave me a Memory error because of the size of both the matrices

```
print(type(image_features))
--> <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
print(type(feature_names))
--> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

print(image_features.shape)
--> (140047, 34464)
print(feature_names.shape)
--> (140047, 2)
```

*First rows of both the matrices for reference*

```
print(image_features[0].toarray())
--> array([[0.       , 0.       , 0.       , ..., 0.       , 0.6384238,
        0.       ]])
print(feature_names[0])
--> array(['00007787805e474ea3f33c722178f550', 'Men'], dtype=object)
```

Updates:

- Converting image_feature into an array will give a memory error
- Doing image_feature.astype('O') will give a memory error

Output:

- I want an output to be a sparse matrix.

Comment: Impossible.  `image_features` is too big the make dense.  `feature_names` can't be made into a float sparse matrix.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with numpy? This could be quite easily worked with if you use pandas. I will add that in the solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Try **either/or** of the following methods. I think the second method will work in your case.

```py
import numpy as np

# Method-1: 2 elements' tuple array data for feature_names
np.hstack([image_features.astype('O'), feature_names[:, np.newaxis])

# Method-2: 2 columns array data for feature_names
np.hstack([image_features.astype('O'), 
           np.array(feature_names.tolist()).reshape(-1,2).astype('O')])

# Method-3: using pandas
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(image_features)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(feature_names.tolist()).reshape(-1,2).astype('O'), columns=['ID', 'Gender'])
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
#df.head()
df.to_numpy()
```

#### Example

We will make some dummy data and test the solution given above.

```
import numpy as np

image_features = np.random.rand(2,10).round(3)
feature_names = np.array([('00007787805e474ea3f33c722178f550', 'Male'), 
                          ('00007787805e474ea3f33c722223f550', 'Female')], 
                        dtype=[('ID', 'O'),('Gender', 'O')])
print('Shape BEFORE newaxis addition: {}'.format((image_features.shape, 
                                                  feature_names.shape)))
feature_names = feature_names[:, np.newaxis]
print('Shape AFTER newaxis addition: {}'.format((image_features.shape, 
                                                 feature_names.shape)))
stacked = np.hstack([image_features.astype('O'), feature_names])
print(stacked)
```

Output:

```
Shape BEFORE newaxis addition: ((2, 10), (2,))
Shape AFTER newaxis addition: ((2, 10), (2, 1))
[[0.335 0.576 0.769 0.442 0.34 0.938 0.745 0.085 0.617 0.643
  ('00007787805e474ea3f33c722178f550', 'Male')]
 [0.689 0.959 0.57 0.122 0.328 0.421 0.176 0.797 0.364 0.495
  ('00007787805e474ea3f33c722223f550', 'Female')]]
```

For more clarity let us use pandas to show this:

```py
import pandas as pd
print(pd.DataFrame(stacked))
```

```
      0      1   ...     9                                           10
0  0.335  0.576  ...  0.643    (00007787805e474ea3f33c722178f550, Male)
1  0.689  0.959  ...  0.495  (00007787805e474ea3f33c722223f550, Female)
```

Comment: ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
This error is coming in your solution

Comment: Did you try the example?

Comment: The example will help you understand how they get stacked using **`numpy.hstack`** and **not** `scipy.sparse.hstack`. Also, you can always extract the values from the structured array as `feature_names.tolist()` and then recast this into a numpy array as `np.array(feature_names.tolist()).reshape(-1,2)`.

Comment: @Rahul Made some changes. Please check now.

Comment: Yes I tried your example its working fine..but my feature_names is a list of lists and as I changed that part and made it a list of lists in your example it gave me the same error.

Comment: Ok. I am making another change to it as we speak. Please check in a minute and leave comment if it worked.

Comment: Can you please put in the exact dimensions and datatypes once to check the solution so as to get confirmed because at my end the solution is giving me an error

Comment: @Rahul Please share some dummy data that I can directly copy paste and check with you. Your dummy data should be in the form of a code that I can run and load in. Only then we would have the same thing to compare with.

Comment: Try method-2 and method-3.

Comment: Hey I appreciate your efforts very much..The np.hstack is actually giving a memory...is there a way that I can get the data into a sparse matrix,without getting the memory error.

Comment: The second matrix is actually a csr matrix please see that as well.

Comment: Ok. I see. There must be a way to convert regular numpy array into sparse array. `sA = sparse.csr_matrix(A)` where `A` is a numpy array. But in that case, (I think and am not entirely sure) `A` should be numeric. I would suggest you use `LabelEncoder` from `Scikit-Learn` to encode the categorical features using numeric values and then use it to hstack with `image_features`.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion but the first column i.e. ID in the feature_names is a unique value column so that also will not work.

Comment: Since each ID is unique, just assign an integer to it. For instance, if you had 1000 such ID's, you could assign integers `0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 999` to the IDs as labels. In fact, the `LabelEncoder` will do precisely this. Since, now each field only needs less data to store, this reduces your memory requirement.

Comment: I can not compromise changing the ID's as well because I have this ID as a foreign key to my main table using this ID I have to align everything and build a model on top of it.

Comment: See the documentation of LabelEncoder and you would realize that it creates a map between the IDs and the Labels (encoded labels) created. So flipping back to your original ID's is very simple.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://towardsdatascience.com/encoding-categorical-features-21a2651a065c

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the csr matrix to a numpy array.
 `temp = np.array(hstack((image_features,sparse.csr_matrix(feature_names))), dtype='desired dtype')`

Edit: Have you tried to convert it using `.toarray()` or `.todense()`?

Comment: Its giving me an error  -- TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)

Comment: Yes I tried it but that is giving me a memory error as the data is quite large